# Issue while loading float columns to destination table through SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sqldatatypes, oledbconnection, dataflowtask

I have a situation where in source table, there are 4 columns having data type float.
When I created new destination table with same schema (having data type float only) the values are loading as 0.
This does not happen when I transfer data manually running SSIS but when ssis package is run from SQL agent. Are there any such chances where float values gets converted to 0?

Comment: Dont use float. Import as string and do your magic on the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially an authentication issue? are you sure the user in the connections is the same? Often on the server configurations come into play & aren't necessarily doing what you expect.

Are you sure the package on the server is up to date? Maybe try deleting the package from the server & uploading it again.